# How to make a certain div activate

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say you have div1 and div2 both with an opacity of .40. How would I be able to make the opacity 1.0 for only div2 when hovered upon?

Comment: Is div2 inside div1 (or vice versa) or are they completely separate?

Comment: The divs are completely separate of each other.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Aaaah thank you, I was confused on the tag part.

Comment: @Antonyous to help others, mark the answer that answered your question as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/9fa5of01/) on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7K2Z3/) by IrvinDominin. The easiest thing is to leverage different class names - drive the behavior that way.

```
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onmouseenter = function (event) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if (rows[j] === this) {
            rows[j].className += " other";
        }
    }
};


rows[i].onmouseleave = function (event) {
    var hovers = document.getElementsByClassName('other');
    var len = hovers.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        hovers[0].className = hovers[0].className.replace(/\sother(\s|$)/, '');
    }
};
```

}